# NVMe drive not detected after changing GPU

Tags: bios, gpu, nvme, m.2

I have a custom built PC that has been working properly for a couple of years, the OS is installed in an NVMe M.2 that I remember was complicated to setup with Secure Boot back when I built it, but it was working fine.

Today, I moved the GPU (an nVidia GTX 1080) from the bottom PCIe slot to the top one, because I just found out in the BIOS that it's supposed to be in that one when only one is used.

Right after moving it to the top slot (no other HW changes) I booted, and the screen said "No media detected, checking media presence" and then went to the BIOS screen. In the boot section I can see that it no longer detects the m.2 drive with the Windows installation.

I tried a few things, reset the keys for secure boot, with no luck.

I will now try moving the GPU back to the bottom slot, but I'd like to be able to use it the way the manufacturer recommends - so is there anything I have to do in order for the computer to recognise the m.2 drive after the change?

I have the feeling it has to do with secure boot, maybe it gets locked when you make a change like this, but I don't know enough about it to debug the issue.

### Hardware:

- Motherboard: [Asus Prime B360-Plus](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/PRIME-B360-PLUS/)
- NVMe Drive: [Samsung Evo 960](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/960evo/)
- GPU: [MSI nVidia GTX 0180](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-card/geforce-gtx-1080-gaming-x-8g.html)

### Update:

I have tried going back to the original setup, with the GPU in the original slot to no avail. Also tried all possible configurations with the 2 M.2 slots and the 2 PCIe slots for the GPU.

Tried booting into Win10 from a USB to run the troubleshooter, but it couldn't find the problem because the drive is not detected - so it can't really troubleshoot that.

Tried disabling secure boot and resetting the keys. Didn't help.

Comment: I have contacted Samsung warranty and support to see if it can be replaced. I just seems to have died but I don't have another computer where I can test it.